# Misplaced ring above A using TeX Gyre Pagella

Tags: fonts, accents

In the below MWE using TeX Gyre Pagella the ring above the A, as produced using `\r{A}`, is misplaced as shown below:

[image]

I expected it to render with the ring centered above the A, shown below, as when using Computer Modern:

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont
    \r{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fixed this by importing the T1 font encoding using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, however I'm not sure why this is needed and will thus wait for someone else to come with a wiser answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use font encoding `T1`. Then you get the full glyph, not a composite one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont
    \r{A}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Is this really all the T1 font encoding does? I guess that works.

Comment: @miestasmia The default encoding `OT1` is a 7-bit encoding without accented letters. Encoding `T1` has place for 256 glyphs (8-bit) and provides slots for accented letters, that are provided by the TeX Gyre fonts. The result is one glyph (capital letter A with ring), designed by the font developers, instead of a more or less well placed ring accent on a capital letter A as with encoding `OT1`.